# In summernote, style tag is removed after toggling from codeview in Angular 15

Tags: text-editor, rich-text-editor, summernote

I am using summernote in my project, I configured as mentioned in the document,
when Toggling from codeview to normal view, Style tags are removed in my application.
But in summernoteJS it is working as expected, style tags are not been removed.

How can we include style tags after toggling to normal view.
I am adding images for reference.

I added plain Html text in codeview.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrE6K.png)
after toggling from codeview, the style tag is missing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL4L4.png)

need to get style tags after toggling to normal view.